# Product landing page (freeCodeCamp Responsive Web Design project)

Tags: html, css

I would appreciate som feedback on my fictional product landing page. I am doing the freeCodeCamp curriculum and [Product Landing Page](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/responsive-web-design-projects/build-a-product-landing-page) is one of the Responsive Web Design Projects using only HTML/CSS.

I am especially interested in feedback regarding best practice, naming conventions and efficient code.

---

The code is also [on GitHub](https://oyvind-solberg.github.io/fcc-product-landing-page/).

#### HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4dd9b52bee.js"></script>
        <title>Fireworks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <div class="flex-row-center">
                <div>
                    <img
                        id="header-img"
                        src="img/Logo.png"
                        alt="Company logo"
                        width="1068px"
                        height="132px"
                    />
                </div>
                <nav id="nav-bar">
                    <ul class="flex-row">
                        <li><a href="#showcase" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#newsletter" class="nav-link">Newsletter</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="social-icons">
                    <ul class="flex-row">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <aside class="social-icons">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </aside>

        <main>
            <section id="showcase">
                <div class="flex-column-center left-align content">
                    <p class="sub-header">Get ready for</p>
                    <h1>
                        <i class="logo-icon fas fa-haykal fa-xs"></i
                        >Fireworks<br />of flavors
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="product-video flex-row-center">
                    <div class="video-container">
                        <video id="video" autoplay loop muted>
                            <source src="video/fireworksHD.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                            <source src="video/fireworksHD.webm" type="video/webm">
                            <source src="video/fireworksHD.ogv" type="video/ogv">
                        </video>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
                <div class="product-img flex-row-center">
                    <img class="standard_img" src="img/Product.png" alt="Fireworks coffee" />
                    <img class="mobile_img" src="img/Product_mobile.png" alt="Fireworks coffee" />              
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="pricing">
                <div class="flex-row-center content">
                    <div class="flex-column-center left-align">
                        <h2>Pricing</h2>
                        <h3 class="sub-header">Monthly subscription</h3>
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="flex-row container-centered shadow">
                        <div class="price-tag">
                            <h3>Personal</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>&dollar;<strong class="price-strong">10</strong>/mo</li>
                                <li>10 bags of coffee</li>
                                <li><a class="btn" href="#">Order Now</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="price-tag focus-line">
                            <h3 class="focus">Professional</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>&dollar;<strong class="price-strong">150</strong>/mo</li>
                                <li>200 bags of coffee</li>
                                <li><a class="btn focus-bg" href="#">Order Now</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="price-tag">
                            <h3>Corporate</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li>&dollar;<strong class="price-strong">600</strong>/mo</li>
                                <li>1000 bags of coffee</li>
                                <li><a class="btn" href="#">Order Now</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <section id="newsletter">
                <div class="flex-row-center content">
                    <div class="flex-column-center left-align">
                        <h2>Newsletter</h2>
                        <h3 class="sub-header">Let's keep in touch</h3>
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="flex-row container-centered shadow">
                        <form class="flex-column"
                            action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit"
                            method="GET"
                            id="form"
                        >
                            <h3 class="focus">E-mail subscription</h3>
                            <input
                                id="email"
                                type="email"
                                name="email"
                                placeholder="Enter your e-mail"
                            />
                            <input class="btn focus-bg" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </section>
        </main>

        <footer>
            <p class="footer-text">
                &copy; 2019 Fireworks all rights reserved
            </p>
            <div class="footer-logo">
                <img
                        id="header-img"
                        src="img/Logo.png"
                        alt="Company logo"
                        width="1068px"
                        height="132px"
                    />
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### CSS file:

```css
/* Color scheme */
:root {
    --background: #000;
    --background-dark: #555;

    --text-standard: #ccc;
    --text-subtle: #777;
    --text-title: #fff;
    --focus: #f98836;
    --focus-highlight: #e27426;
}

/* Basic Reset */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Setup */
body {
    background-color: var(--background);
    color: var(--text-standard);
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--text-title);
}

ul,
li {
    list-style: none;
}

input[type="submit"] {
    border: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.logo-icon {
    color: var(--focus);
    margin-right: 0.1em;
    transform: translateY(-0.1em);
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: var(--text-title);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: var(--text-title);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: var(--text-title);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sub-header {
    color: var(--focus);
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

/* Utility classes */
.flex-row-center {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.flex-column-center {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.flex-row {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container-centered {
    margin: auto;
}

.left-align {
    align-items: flex-start;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 12rem 10rem 12rem 6rem;
}

.shadow {
    box-shadow: 5px 20px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), 5px 5px 100px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)
}

.focus {
    color: var(--focus);
}

body .focus-bg {
    background-color: var(--focus);
}

.mobile_img {
    display: none;
}

/* Buttons */
.btn {
    background-color: var(--background-dark);
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    color: var(--text-title);
}

body .btn:hover {
    background-color: var(--focus-highlight);
}

/* Header */
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 6rem;
    padding-top: 3rem;
    z-index: 100;
}

header::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7rem;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0006, #0006 60%, #0000);
    z-index: -1;
}

header img {
    width: 12rem;
}

header .social-icons {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    right: 3rem;
    top: 2.5rem;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

header .social-icons li {
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

/* Nav */
#nav-bar a {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
    margin-left: 5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav-bar a:hover {
    color: var(--focus);
}

/* Aside */
.social-icons {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    right: 4rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 100;
}
.social-icons a {
    color: var(--text-subtle);
}

.social-icons li {
    margin: 2rem 0;
}

/* Showcase */
#showcase {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: radial-gradient(#ffffff34, #ffffff17);
}

#showcase .product-img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10rem;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#showcase img {
    max-width: 1600px;
}

#showcase .product-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 10rem;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#showcase .video-container {
    max-width: 1600px;
}

#showcase .product-video video {
    width: 100%;
}

#showcase .sub-header {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

/* Pricing */
#pricing {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: radial-gradient(#ffffff34, #ffffff17);
}

.price-tag {
    color: var(--text-subtle);
    width: 12rem;
    padding: 2rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: var(--text-subtle);
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.price-strong {
    color: var(--text-title);
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0 0.1em;
}

#pricing li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 2rem 0 0 0;

}

#pricing li:first-child {
    margin-top: 0.3rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#pricing li:last-child {
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.focus-line {
    border-color: var(--focus);
    border-width: 1.5px;
    outline: 2px solid;
    outline-color: var(--focus);
    z-index: 100;
}


/* Newsletter */
#newsletter {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: radial-gradient(#ffffff34, #ffffff17);
}

#newsletter form {
    width: 32rem;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: var(--text-subtle);
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
}

#newsletter form h3 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

input[type="email"] {
    padding: 0.5rem;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}

/* Footer */
footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

footer::before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7rem;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #0006, #0006 60%, #0000);
    z-index: -1;
}

.footer-text {
    position: fixed;
    left: 6rem;
    bottom: 3rem;
    color: var(--text-subtle);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.footer-logo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 8rem;
    bottom: 3rem;
    color: var(--text-subtle);
    width: 7rem;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

/* Media queries */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #pricing > .flex-row-center,
    #newsletter > .flex-row-center {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #pricing .left-align,
    #newsletter .left-align {
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        flex: 0;
    }
    #pricing .sub-header,
    #newsletter .sub-header {
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    aside.social-icons,
    #nav-bar {
        display: none;
    }
    header .social-icons {
        display: flex;
    }
    header img {
        width: 8rem;
    }
    .content {
        padding: 6rem 3rem 6rem 3rem;
    }
    #pricing .content,
    #newsletter .content {
        padding: 10rem 3rem 10rem 3rem;
    }
    header {
        left: 3rem;
        padding-top: 2rem;
    }
    #showcase .left-align {
        align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .footer-text {
        left: 3rem;
        bottom: 2rem;
    }
    .footer-logo {
        right: 3rem;
        bottom: 2rem;
    }
    #showcase .product-img,
    #showcase .product-video {
        top: 15%;
        left: 0;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 3rem;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 2.3rem;
    }
}
/* Tablet 768px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #showcase .product-img,
    #showcase .product-video {
        top: 10%;
        left: 0;
    }
    #pricing {
        height: auto;
    }
    #pricing .flex-row {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    #pricing .flex-row,
    .price-tag {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .price-tag {
        padding: 2rem; 
    }
    #newsletter .flex-row,
    #newsletter form {
        width: 100%;
    } 
    #newsletter form {
        padding: 2rem 2rem;
    }
}

/* Phone 568px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    header .social-icons li {
        margin-left: 0.8rem;
    }
    #pricing .content,
    #newsletter .content {
        padding: 1rem 2rem 5rem 2rem;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
    .footer-logo {
        display: none;
    }
    .footer-text {
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0 2rem;
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    }
    #newsletter {
        height: auto;
    }
    #showcase img,
    #showcase video {
        width: 150%;
        left: -25%;
    }
    #video {
        display: none;
    }
    .standard_img {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile_img {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! "this is one of the Responsive Web Design Projects", which one specifically?

Comment: Thank you! Build a Product Landing Page.

[Link to website](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/responsive-web-design/responsive-web-design-projects/build-a-product-landing-page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```html
> width="1068px"
> height="132px"
> ```

The `width` and `height` attributes can’t contain "px".

```html
width="1068"
height="132"
```

---

The `alt` value for the logo should not contain "logo", just the company name.

---

> ```html
> <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
> ```

Don’t use the `i` element if you just want to display an icon via CSS. The `i` element has a meaning which isn’t appropriate for this ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501699/1591669)). Use the `span` element instead.

```html
<span class="fab fa-facebook-f"></span>
```

---

> ```html
> <h1>
>   <i class="logo-icon fas fa-haykal fa-xs"></i
>   >Fireworks<br />of flavors
> </h1>
> ```

Don’t use the `br` element if you want to show a line break just because of aesthetic reasons. The `br` element must only be used for meaningful line breaks ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13221418/1591669)). Use a `span` element and CSS to add the line break.

```html
<h1>
  <span class="logo-icon fas fa-haykal fa-xs"></span
  >Fireworks <span class="separator">of flavors</span>
</h1>
```

---

Your use of heading elements is not consistent. Your first `section` starts with `h1`, your second `section` starts with `h2`. While this is not an error, it’s a good practice to be consistent: either use `h1` everywhere, or (preferably) use the heading elements of the correct rank, i.e., start with `h2` in top-level sections.

---

> ```html
> <h2>Pricing</h2>
> <h3 class="sub-header">Monthly subscription</h3>
> ```

Don’t use a heading element for sub-headings ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22451639/1591669)). This creates a wrong document outline. Use a `p` element instead.

```html
<h2>Pricing</h2>
<p class="sub-header">Monthly subscription</p>
```

---

> ```html
> /mo
> ```

You can use the `abbr` element here.

```html
<abbr title="per month">/mo</abbr>
```

---

> ```html
> <p class="footer-text">
>     &copy; 2019 Fireworks all rights reserved
> </p>
> ```

You can use the `small` element here ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21489636/1591669)).

```html
<p class="footer-text">
  <small>&copy; 2019 Fireworks all rights reserved</small>
</p>
```

---

Both of your logo `img` element have the same `id` value. An `id` value can only be used once per page.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed feedback! Exactly what I was looking for.

Regarding heading elements, I have now wraped a h1 tag around my logo image in the header and changed all my top-level-sections to h2.
I'm a bit unsure if this is the correct use of the h1 tag, but I see Facebook is doing the same so I guess it is ok.

Comment: @Øyvindsen: I would say having the site name (whether it’s text or a logo) as `h1` is ideal; many people disagree because they have the (outdated, I would say) assumption that `h1` should only be used for the main content, but this would typically lead to a wrong document outline. -- You can check the document outline with https://validator.w3.org/nu/ -- there is a checkbox "outline".

Comment: Thanks. I'm already familiar with the validator. Guess I need to remember to use it more often. Now the outline looks good. It just takes the `alt` value from the image as the h1 text.